# Flexera Installshield 2015 Uninstall Custom Action before System Changes

Tags: installation, exe, installshield

I'm running into an issue using installshield as installerproject for my windows service.

I have an exe which I can run with *-I*
 which installs my project as windows service.

This executes fine as I can set the param in the last dialog where "Show Launch Program" is set true.

But now when I'm uninstalling the whole program it should run the command

`/Program Files(x86)/company/app/main.exe`

command with *-U* parameter.

But I can only specify custom action to run after the main.exe has already been deleted.

Does anyone knows a way to run my custom action before the uninstallation process deletes my files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the installed version of installshield.

With the Limited Edition (LE) you are just able to create custom actions in some dedicated steps and not everywhere while installing.

I've written now an own command line file which I'm providing together with the SETUP.exe.